# php node.js read file deffrent result

Tags: javascript, php, node.js

this image the file that I have it its wav file[image]

php code for read first four byte

```
$handle = fopen($filename, "r");
 $heading[] = fread($handle, 4);
```

this give me

> RIFF

and thats good also in node.js same result now for second four byte

```
$handle = fopen($filename, "r");
$heading[] = fread($handle, 4);
$heading[] = fread($handle, 4);
```

its give me only

> l¬

but in node.js give me

> l¬ space space thats mean (l¬   )

the problem with nul value in file

my node.js read file its

```
  fs.open(fileName, "r", function(error, fd) {
   var buffer = new Buffer(4);
  fs.read(fd, buffer, 0, 4, 4, function(error, bytesRead, buffer) {
   var data = buffer.toString("utf8", 0, bytesRead);
  console.log(data+"ds");


   fs.close(fd);
   });
   });
```

thats make for me problem when convert data to hex its give me deffrent result

when i convert the

> (l¬ nul nul)

by php be **6cac0000**

but in node.js its read its as space and result will be 6cefbfbd00

just for be sure the

> (l¬)

in php and node.js give same result when convert to hex

but

> (l¬ nul nul)

give deffrent result